# Error while reading a polynomial from a JTextField in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a polynomial coefficients and degree from a  JTextField and then to create with them a monomial that will be added to a  polynomial , but I am getting the error " index Out Of Bound " when i try to split the String and i do not understand why.Can anyone help me with some advice?
This is my code:

```
public Polynomial readPol(JTextField pol){

        String s = pol.getText();
        String[] parts;
        Polynomial auxP = new Polynomial();
        Monommial aux;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            parts = s.split("x^");//this is where a get the error
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            int coef;
            if (part1.compareTo("-") == 0)
                coef = -1;
            else {
                if (part1.compareTo("+") == 0)
                    coef = 1;
                else
                    coef = Integer.parseInt(part1);
            }
            int grad = Integer.parseInt(part2);
            aux = new Monomial(coef, grad);
            auxP.addTerm((Monomial) aux);
        }
        return auxP;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually get the error a couple lines after it:

```
String part2 = parts[1];
```

You want to split on `^`,  which you need to escape using `\\`.

```
parts = s.split("\\^");
```

Also, check out `string.startsWith("+");`, which might be a bit cleaner.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Don't forget that you can accept answers, and now that you have over 15 points on your account, you can vote them up too.